# how can my javascript code access a local file?

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm using opencv.js. and I'm implementing TI filter(Temporary information).

```
const calculateTI = videoPath => {
      console.log(videoPath);

      const videoCapture = new cv.VideoCapture("videoPath", videoPath); // Please input the valid video element or id.
      console.log(videoCapture);

      const tiResults = [];

      let frame = new cv.Mat();
      while (true) {
        videoCapture.read(frame);

        if (frame.empty()) break;

        const tiResult = cv.mean(frame);
        tiResults.push(tiResult);
      }

      videoCapture.delete();
      frame.delete();
      return tiResults;
    };

    console.log(calculateTI(fileUri)); //Please input the valid video element or id.
```

fileUri is like 'file:///C:Users/user/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

but, I got an error 'Please input the valid video element or id'.

and I tried to `const videoCapture = new cv.VideoCapture(videoPath);`

but the same...

If anyone knows about opencv and ti filter, please reply.

Comment: Arbitrary web pages can't access client's filesystem.

Comment: @Teemu If I can't access the file system, I don't know what to do. Do you know about the TI filter I mentioned?

Comment: Your code doesn't need a file but a `<video>` element, see the answer. If you really want the user to upload a video file from the file system you can build a "file" form field. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Answer (score 1):

Create video element:

```
<video id="myvideo src="path here">
```

Use it:

```
new cv.VideoCapture(document.querySelector('#myvideo'))
```